# how to trigger shift + left mouse click in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

There are 2 anchor elements as shown below.

```
<a (click)="popupIconClick()">Click Here</a>
<a #newWindow (click)="openInNewWindow($event)">New Window</a>
```

when first element is clicked, it invokes `popupIconClick()` function in my .ts file. This finds the `#newWindow` element and should invoke the click function for this element but the click event should behave as if it was performed with shift key pressed.

```
popupIconClick() {
  const newWindowElement = document.querySelector(`#newWindow`);
  //should invoke shift+click for newWindowElement
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dispatch a `MouseEvent` with `shiftKey` set to true

```
newWindowElement.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click", { shiftKey: true}));
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/shiftKey

Comment: thank you. 
In Chrome, when an anchor tag is clicked with shift+click it opens a browser in new window with address bar, tab bar etc. but is there any way to achieve this behavior by just clicking the anchor tag (without shift) and open the browser in new window with address bar, tab bar? 
Tried with the above approach you suggested by dispatching a MouseEvent with shiftKey set to true. But it behaved like a normal click and opened the link in the same window. Any inputs on this would be really helpful.

Comment: I have a simple test page here https://codepen.io/atwayne/pen/vYyWezJ . if you click the without shift button it will open within the window while the shift button will open in a new window. looks like exactly what you want

Comment: could you create an example that doesn't work?

Comment: thank you for the codepen example. have modified the code and it worked fine as expected